# Laravel authentication: how to get user attributes?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I would like to check account status in Middleware. The status is represented by tinyint. if it is 1 then it is activated, otherwise 0.

In App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate, I have:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->input('status') == 0)
    {
        Session::flash('message', 'Your account hasn\'t been activated, please try again later.');
        return redirect('/');
    }

    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

$request->input('status') == 0 is probably wrong. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend checking if the user is a guest before you check the status. Otherwise, you'd be trying to grab the status of guests, which is not possible.

Second, you have access to the user with the `user` method so you can just grab the status off the user like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
        }
    }

    if ($this->auth->user()->status === 0) {
        Session::flash('message', 'Your account hasn\'t been activated, please try again later.');
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Extra tidbit: Laravel has a [`$casts`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) property you can add to your models. So, if you add this to your User model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'status' => 'boolean'
];
```

It will automatically convert "cast" `status` into a boolean value so you can just do this:

```
if (!$this->auth->user()->status) {
    // User's status is false
}
```